# AWS SDK gives 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I keep getting an error in main.js every time I do 'npm run build':

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

It disappears once I refresh the page. I've done some debugging and I found out that there are two libraries which causes that issue:

```
"aws-sdk": "^2.295.0"
```

and

```
"react-data-export": "^0.4.2"
```

If one of them is imported to any js file, I get this error. Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

guess you need to send a `cache-control: no-cache;` HTTP header, in order to disable the caching, whenever a `.js` is not found in the static assets and `index.html` (or some other `404` page) is being returned. then you won't have to refresh the page manually.

Comment: Where do I need to add it?

Comment: @GrzegorzBrzęczyszczykiewicz to the web-server configuration or `.htaccess` (that might vary, depending which web-server you use).

Comment: Website is on heroku as well as the server which is in nodejs. Does it help you?

Comment: @GrzegorzBrzęczyszczykiewicz with nodeJS, you'd have to send the header yourself. https://github.com/indexzero/http-server Caching is on by default. Add `-c-1` as an option to disable caching (this would send the suggested header). you could ask disable it in the browser, because that cache is client-side.

Comment: I am using nodejs just for express requests. Is it going to work in such a scenario?

Comment: @GrzegorzBrzęczyszczykiewicz whatever serves the page would need to send the header.

Comment: that should be `res.set('cache-control', 'no-cache');` ...according to https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set

Comment: @GrzegorzBrzęczyszczykiewicz that should be about the same, using middleware... as the API docs show, `res.header()` only exists there (thought it would be just the same, but it isn't).

Comment: I've addded that : 'app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    next()
});' but it seems it didn't help. I can see that header in a response on client side tho. Could you explain me how it is supposed to work? Because, it seems that I have a problem with js files on the client side, not with the requests from the server.

Comment: The problem is actually with caching the main.js file. It is too big. I am working to fix that right now.